# How do you add a data table to the chartspace with openpyxls?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

There is an `openpyxl.chart.chartspace.DataTable` class in openpyxl, however no examples. When I try to use it I get either:

```
AttributeError: 'BarChart' object has no attribute 'DataTable'
```

Or I don't get the datatable in the chartspace with this code:

```
from openpyxl.chart.chartspace import DataTable

chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.DataTable = DataTable(showHorzBorder=None , showVertBorder=None,showOutline=None, showKeys=None, spPr=None,txPr=None, extLst=None)
```

Comment: It's not been implemented yet. The whole chart part of the OOXML is hideously complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe It's too late.. This works for me

```
from openpyxl.chart.plotarea import DataTable

chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.plot_area.dTable = DataTable()
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showHorzBorder = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showVertBorder = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showOutline = True
chart1.plot_area.dTable.showKeys = True
```